# list of list but specific representations in python

Tags: python, list

I don't have much experience about lists in Python. So basically, I want to create N list inside one huge list. Reading from a file that looks like this:

```
Fail = h yes
Sucess = h no
```

This is an example of 2 lines in the file, and the file contains N line, thus I want to create a list for each line such that it should be:

```
List of list = [
        ["Fail", ("h", "yes")],
        ["Sucess", ("h", "no")]],]
```

And in case a line of:

```
Fail = h
```

with only one output, its list should be like:

```
["Fail", ("h", )),]
```

My code doesn't work for now,:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
     for l in f:
         l_rule = l.split()
        # print(l_rule)
         G_list.append(l_rule[0])
         length= len(l_rule)
         if length == 3:

                 m = "(" + l_rule[2]+ "," +")"
                 G_list.append(m)


         else:


                 m = "(" + l_rule[2]+","+l_rule[3] +")"
                 G_list.append(m)

         print(G_list)
         listoflist.append(G_list)

print(listoflist)
```

And it doesn't return what I need as I explained above. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Note that `["Fail", ("h", )),]` is syntactically invalid. I assume you meant `["Fail", ("h", )]`.

Answer (score 2):

Split each line and unpack it. Then you can check whether the necessary last element was found, and create the appropriate tuple. Append the result to your list of results.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    result = []
    for line in f:
        a,b,c,*d = line.split()
        if d:
            tup = c,d[0]
        else:
            tup = c,
        result.append([a, tup])
```

Comment: Hmm, couldn't you get away with just doing `tup = (c,) + tuple(d)` without the checking?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use string functions to create tuple - `("h", "yes")`

You need

```
m = ( l_rule[2], ) 

m = ( l_rule[2], l_rule[3] )
```

---

**EDIT:** I found you have to clear `G_list` before you add new elements

```
 G_list = []

 G_list.append(l_rule[0])
```

---

**EDIT:** code with modifications

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
     for l in f:

         l_rule = l.split()

         G_list = []  # clear list

         G_list.append(l_rule[0])

         length= len(l_rule)

         if length == 3:
                 m = (l_rule[2],)  # create tuple instead of string
                 G_list.append(m)
         else:
                 m = (l_rule[2], l_rule[3])  # create tuple instead of string
                 G_list.append(m)

         print(G_list)
         listoflist.append(G_list)

print(listoflist)
```

Comment: Can you explain more? and post the exact editions? I couldn't understand

Comment: you create single string `'("h", "yes")'` not tuple with two elements `"h"` and `"yes"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def format_data(line):
    lst = line.split()
    return lst[0], tuple(lst[2:])

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        G_list.append(format_data(l))
listoflist.append(G_list)
```

or you can do a one_liner inside your `with` statement.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    listoflist = [format_data(l) for l in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way is to do two passes of splitting, first by `=` and then by whitespace (default for `split`). Use `strip` as necessary:

```
>>> import io
>>> s = """Fail = h yes
... Sucess = h no
... Fail = h """
>>> 
>>> L = [line.strip().split('=') for line in io.StringIO(s)]
>>> [[sub[0].strip(),tuple(sub[1].strip().split())] for sub in L]
[['Fail', ('h', 'yes')], ['Sucess', ('h', 'no')], ['Fail', ('h',)]]
>>>
```

If memory is an issue, you can adapt the above to process the lines lazily.